# Executing a list of Futures, Only first two in the list get executed - Scala

Tags: scala, future

I have the following code and `readCSV` reads from a path and dumps records in database. However only for the first two list values do I see rows in the DB. Any idea what's wrong? I want `readCSV` to be executed for all the AccountListValues. `readCSV` returns a `Future[Unit]`.

```
val AccountsList = List("account", "accountstd","accountcvg","accountcvgstd")

val futuresBuffer = new ListBuffer[Future[Unit]]()
taskInput.dataSet.foreach(exporttype => {
  exporttype.toLowerCase match {
    case "accounts" => {
      AccountsList.foreach(tableName => {
        logger.info(s"Listvalue $tableName")
        val csvPath = wrapper.filter(s"/${taskInput.parquetFilePath}/$tableName/*.csv").get(0)
        logger.info(s"csvPath - $csvPath")
        futuresBuffer += sqlBulkCopy.readCSVFile(csvPath,
          taskInput.sqlServerJdbcString, tableName, rmsStorageWrapper)
      })
    }
    case "geography" =>
    case "locations" =>
  }
})
   
val remaining = new AtomicInteger(futuresBuffer.length)
futuresBuffer foreach {
  _ onComplete {
    case s@ Success(_) => {
      if (remaining.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
        // Arbitrarily return the final success
        s.value
      }
    }
    case f@Failure(_) => {
      logger.error(f.exception.getMessage)
    }
  }//onComplete
}
```

Comment: With what you have here it feels most likely that `csvPath` has no data for `accountcvg` and `accountcvgstd`, but it's very difficult to diagnose a real issue here, please try to create a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: You probably want something like [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/uhhLXMskSpWf1I4QHFTc7Q/3) using `Future.traverse` - btw, I would recommend you to pick any basic **Scala** tutorial, there is more in this language than just syntax.

Comment: The problem you are likely encountering is that once the callbacks on all the futures in `futuresBuffer` have been scheduled (not necessarily executed), your code snippet has returned (of note `s.value` is meaningless here: it can only ever be the singleton value for `Unit` (spelled `()`).